# How does my HTML file get access to my Javascript file via gh-pages?

Tags: html, git, github, github-pages

I am currently having trouble understanding how gh-pages functions with file communication.

I currently have two files in my gh-pages branch on my github: `bundle.js` and `index.html`. When running this locally, `index.html` has access to `bundle.js` by moving through file paths. When running this online I have an issue getting `index.html` to be able to access `bundle.js`correctly.

1st attempt: I found the raw text through the URL: `https://raw.githubusercontent.com/...`. Unfortunately this does not work because there is a MIME type error.

2nd attempt: I found that there is another source for raw text that doesn't have the MIME type error, the URL is: `https://cdn.rawgit.com/...`. Unfortunately this does not work because `cdn.rawgit.com` does not update itself.

3rd attempt: I have found that I can use the same method as my 2nd attempt, but I can use a specific commit to access the correct `cdn.rawgit.com/.../<commit path>`. This seems to make things much more difficult because I would have to update my `index.html` every time I want to update the page. This also doesn't seem possible because how would I know the commit # before I commit it?

The relevant code is the line `<script src = "https://cdn.rawgit.com/NumaK...">`.
I can't figure out how my `gh-pages` website is supposed to be using the correct version of `bundle.js`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, 
    shrink-to-fit=no">
    <title>Numa Karolinski</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <noscript>
    Hello There. Code can be found in the "root" folder above ^^^ !
    </noscript>
    <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/NumaKarolinski/PersonalWebsite/ 
    websiteVersion1/dist/bundle.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: If bundle.js is in the same folder, why can't you import it directly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your ***index.html***, replace :

```
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/NumaKarolinski/PersonalWebsite/websiteVersion1/dist/bundle.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="C:\Users\numak\Desktop\MyWebsite\dist/bundle.js"></script></body>
```

by

```
<script src="bundle.js"></script>
```

Comment: This works as long as I place my `index.html` and `bundle.js` in the same folder so it works locally as well.